# Is there any possibility to run an Android Application on IOS7,6,5..?or wise versa

Tags: java, android, ios

> i want to make an app in Java

my question is does it possible that Program Written in Java could run on both Platform Android and ios
if yes then What to do any small Tips...
because Java is Platform independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Platform independent doesnt the meaning stated by zaph, It means you can run the same compiled code in what ever operating system which has java. Eg: you can run a java program compiled in windows and copy those class files and you can run it on a linux which has the jre. (While c and c++ are platform dependent)`

You cant run android code in IOS is simply because they dont have java compilers. C and C++ are basic languages used to write operating system, Even java VM is wriiten in c++. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028057/what-language-is-used-to-develop-java-language)

If you want to run an app on both android and IOS . you should go for `PhoneGap` Now a days. We have alternating options like hybrid apps which is already suggested.

Comment: There is a little bit of a play on words between the question and my answer.

Answer (score 4):

No. While Java may be "Platform independent" that does not mean it is supported on all platforms. It is not supported on iOS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply 
if i install JVM on ios then is it Possible ?

Comment: You can't install JVM on iOS, at least not without Jailbreaking (rooting).

Answer (score 2):

No, java use in Android whereas objective-c use in ios.

So, it is not possible.

If you want to run same code on both platform then go hybrid application using `HTML5`, `CSS3` and `javascript` or `jQuery`.

Comment: but Android not support these languages. Android support only java language.

Comment: Java run on windows, that sounds funny, C and C++ are basics of almost all operating systems, But java need Jdk and jre which is not available in IOS.In android we have DVM(Dalvik virtual Machine) to compile those java classes and run the dex files

Answer (score 0):

Running Java on iOS is not supported because of restrictions imposed on the iOS Developer Program License. Though Java is platform independent, an application built using Java, needs a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) to execute bytecode which your Java application ultimately compiles to. Since iOS does not support a JVM, it will not be possible to run Java on an Apple device.

Applications that run on multiple platforms usually run as web views, implying that they are based on HTML. A popular tool in use is PhoneGap or Cordova. You could use these to develop platform-independent applications.